# Decode proprietary LED dimming data

Tags: sockets, tcp, packet, led

I've captured the TCP traffic between the control box and the LED drivers, but I'm not sure what to make of it.

Seems the first string sent is the value, and the second string is some kind of confirmation, or go ahead and do it message.

But how would I send an arbitrary value like 33%

Does anyone see an obvious way to convert this data?

First section below sets the brightness to 100%, second to 75% and so on.

```
:bri100
C:\ps\packetsender.com -q -u 192.168.1.95 9099 "21 00 34 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 3f"
C:\ps\packetsender.com -q -u 192.168.1.95 9099 "10 00 31 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01"

:bri75
C:\ps\packetsender.com -q -u 192.168.1.95 9099 "21 00 34 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 3f"
C:\ps\packetsender.com -q -u 192.168.1.95 9099 "10 00 31 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01"

:bri50
C:\ps\packetsender.com -q -u 192.168.1.95 9099 "21 00 34 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f"
C:\ps\packetsender.com -q -u 192.168.1.95 9099 "10 00 31 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01"

:bri25
C:\ps\packetsender.com -q -u 192.168.1.95 9099 "21 00 34 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 3e"
C:\ps\packetsender.com -q -u 192.168.1.95 9099 "10 00 31 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01"
```

Comment: Can you tell us what these products are?

Comment: It looks to me that last two bytes encode brightness (in little endian) using simple linear formula. If this is true, then 33% brightness would be: `swap_bytes(hex(15936 + (16256-15936)*0.33)) => 0xA93E`.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.

The products are some LED signage (S6F controller) without good documentation other than the Windows program it ships with, that leaves nothing for command-line or API control, meaning all I can do is capture from the crappy software and role my own solution.

Comment: If that Windows software is .NET-based then it could be easily decompiled to a readable code.